# MSC .getElementById or .getElementByClassName

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently having a bit of a problem, because i can't create a proper VBA code for my excel to enter data from cell to particular website. Could You please help me with it ?

```
Sub MSC()

    Dim OrgBox As HTMLInputElement
    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    objIE.navigate "http://www.mscgva.ch/tracking/index.html"
    objIE.Visible = True
    Do While objIE.readyState < 4: Loop

    Set OrgBox = objIE.getElementById("InputBox")
    OrgBox.Value = Range("a1")
    OrgBox.form.submit

End Sub
```

Comment: Needs more detail.  What *exactly* is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The element you're trying to control is in an iframe.  To control elements inside an iframe, you need to extract the src attribute from the  tag and navigate to that URL

```
        ifr_url = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).src
```

in your case ifr_url = "http://tracking.mscgva.ch/msctracking.php"

Once on that webpage your code to insert text should work.